# Xamarin Test Cloud - Upload error, Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-test-cloud

I have noticed in a few threads on the Xamarin Forums ([here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/46579/specify-ios-app-version-when-submitting-to-test-cloud-from-visual-studio), [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/143571)) that people were having troubles uploading an app to Xamarin Test Cloud. Those posts were old but none of the solutions worked.

Error I get is

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

I created a new project with the same bundle ID and the same Info.plist and I am able to upload to XTC with that. But clearly isn't the app I want to test (though I did try out text input and screenshots, this system is awesome).

There is nothing else on my end that I can think of causing the problems. I did notice my .ipa file was about 230mb but had not seen anything about a max filesize for XTC.

I tried to use the --debug option to get more info when I ran the same command to upload from terminal but it did not help. Any suggestions what to do or why XTC servers may be erroring on my files?

Comment: Are you uploading this via Xamarin Studio, Visual Studio or command line?

Comment: @BytesGuy, fails on both. I should have mentioned that. I solved the problem eventually by accident. Issue was I had linker behavior set to "Don't link", changing it to "Link Framework SDKs Only".

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out. Issue was I had linker behavior set to "Don't link", changing it to "Link Framework SDKs Only". 
Hope this helps someone else if they have this issue.